# Why no acceptor energy level in pure semiconductor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Why there is no acceptor energy level in pure semiconductor? (assume some holes are formed due to heat), While the holes created here to effectively conduct electricity , bonded electrons must effectively "hop" into it and thus would cost energy, like in p-type semiconductor where there is a explicit Acceptor Energy level just because electrons take energy to hop into holes.

Hope you understood my question, any extra information regarding this is also highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you'd expect that there *would* be acceptor levels in pure semiconductors?

Comment: @J. Murray because say there is a hole formed in pure semiconductor due to heat, and 1 electron is freed, Now for that hole to conduct electricity neighbouring bonded e- must migrate into the hole and this continues, now that migration takes energy as in p type, so why does p type have acceptor energy level and pure semi conductor doesnt ?

Comment: An *acceptor level* is a level in the band gap just above the top of the valence band. These levels are created by the dopant. Without a dopant there are no levels in the band gap therefore there cannot be an acceptor levels.

Comment: @JohnRennie Can you explain how this level is created, As per my knowledge this acceptor level means "The energy e- need to hop into holes" , doesnt heated pure semi conductors also have same condition ?, which doped p type has, if it takes energy for a Si valence e- to jump into a Boron's Hole, then why doesnt the same happen if a hole is created by heat in Pure Semi conductor ?

Comment: @JohnRennie Oh yes I got where I was wrong, The understanding of Acceptor energy level was wrong in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pure semiconductor, the allowed energy levels form bands separated by gaps. At zero temperature, the valence band is full while the conduction band is empty, and there is a gap (on the order of $\sim 1$ eV) separating the two. If you provide enough thermal energy to create a hole, you're promoting an electron from the valence band all they way up to the conduction band.

On the other hand, if there are acceptor dopants or defects present in the crystal, then in *addition* to the bulk valence and conduction bands, then there are spatially localized energy states which exist within the gap, on the order of $\sim 0.1$ eV above the top of the valence band.  In this case, you would need to provide only $\sim 10\%$ of the energy you would have needed before in order to create a hole by promoting an electron from the filled valence band to the localized acceptor level.

In other words, you can certainly create an electron quasiparticle / hole pair in a pure semiconductor, but to do so you must supply at least as much energy as the band gap between the conduction and valence band.  In the presence of acceptor dopants and defects, there exist special energy levels just above the top of the valence band, and it requires far less energy to promote an electron from the valence band to one of these acceptor levels.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense if the understanding of acceptor energy level of mine is incorrect, so does acceptor energy level mean "to create holes on Semiconductor element atom like Si" ? I thought it was "to transfer e- to holes"

Comment: @ManavSengupta It sounds to me like you may have a misunderstanding about what a hole actually is.  If you have a pure Si crystal and then substitute one of the Si atoms with a Boron atom, then a new energy state will be created. This state will consist of an electron bound to the Boron atom, and the energy of this state will be just slightly above the valence band. This is a so-called "acceptor state." It requires very little energy to promote a (delocalized) electron from the valence band to this localized state, leaving a (delocalized) "hole."

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_hole) for more.

Comment: Yes I had a misunderstanding, I thought the lack of e- in Boron atom was also a hole, But when the silicon atom donated a e- to Boron then it(Si) had a hole which does the conduction, and acceptor energy is that energy which is required to transfer that e- from Si to B, please let me know if it is right ?

Comment: @ManavSengupta That's basically right. It's worth remembering that the states in both the conduction and valence band are spread over the entire crystal, while the acceptor state is localized to whatever impurity is present.

Comment: Ok would Remeber That!, Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt :)